# Multi-categories selection Chart in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am struggling with creating a multi-select column chart in highcharts.
My goal is to let the user be able to select / deselect any category of the chart.

Expect Behavior:

1. On category (i.e - "0 - 1M") click, both bars should change color. Another click on the category will revert the color back.
2. How to notify the external app (AngularJS) of the selected columns?

I am using allowPointSelect: true, but it only select one column and not both columns of the category.

```
allowPointSelect: true,
```

Not sure how to continue from here.

JSfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/w7dvrkhz/9/

Any ideas please?

Comment: Can you explain in detail regarding your Point 1, like a sample graph look alike when you select would be better.

Comment: np. for example - when you select a column in category "0-1M", then both columns would be yellow. clicking again on them, will make them blue again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** This custom behavior can be easily programmed in callback function for `plotOptions.series.point.events.click` property:

```
  point: {
    events: {
        click: function() {
        var clickedPoint = this,
            chart = clickedPoint.series.chart;

        chart.series.forEach(function(s) {
            s.points.forEach(function(p) {
            if(p.x == clickedPoint.x) {
              p.select(null, true);
            }
          });
        });
      }
    }
  },
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/d37x5mo7/

`allowPointSelect` needs to be disabled while using the above code.

**API references:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events.click
- https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#select

---

**2.** I don't know much about Angular, but the event that I used in the 1st point seems to be good place to check which points are currently selected.